# A do while loop to validate textboxes in C# is causing extra curly braces or infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to validate information in textboxes using C# & ASP.NET.

The information is being validated, however will no longer validate after I go through the list of text boxes. I tried to loop until all information is filled but it either causes infinite loop or an extra curly brace.

Here is a snippet of the code

```
if (Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    lblError.Text = "ERROR";
}

if (Request["txtLastName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    txtLastName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    lblError.Text = "ERROR";
}
etc...  

else
{
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;

    DateTime txtStart = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);

    DateTime.Compare(txtStart, endDate);

    if (txtStart > endDate)
    {
        lblError.Text = "start is greater then end";
        txtStartDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtEndDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

No matter where I put the loop either do while or while loop it is not working? Can anyone suggest some tips? Thanks

Comment: Where's the `do`-`while` loop?

Comment: "an extra curly brace" has never hurt anybody

Comment: Please don't ask questions about code that doesn't exist.  How on earth should we know what typo you've made on a page you haven't shown us?

Comment: You will find it easier to get your code correct when you break it up into smaller methods.  Write a helper method: `bool ValidateText(string s) => Request[s].ToString().Trim() != ""` and write another helper method `void ReportError(Control c, string s) { lblError.Text = s; c.BackColor = Yellow; }`  And now your logic is much easier to read:  `if (!ValidateText("txtFirstName")) ReportError(txtFirstName, "ERROR");`

Comment: That said, I don't understand the question in the first place. Why would you be putting a loop into a server page? Handle the request, serve the result, done.  No loop required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would add a return in every check, which should shorten the validation process. Also you should not be using a do-while or while loop since you want the user to be able to fix the error, from what I understand how you setting up the do-while or while loop will only cause an infinite loop. You should set it up this way.

```
protected void someBtn_Click(object o, eventags e)
{
    if (Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        lblError.Text = "ERROR";
        return;
    }
    ....repeat this for all check

    //If everything checks off 
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;

    ....and whatever is left to do
}
```

If you want to highlight all textbox with errors first, add a bool hasError = false at the beginning, change all return to hasError = true, and do a final check before the last step

```
if(hasError)
    return;
```